# How to set caller and pass fee value in ink test-cases?

Tags: ink, smart-contract, substrate-contracts-node

In my contract function, I am checking who is the transaction caller. Since I am not setting the caller in the test-cases, It might be the issue.
I would to know how to set caller_id and how to pass funds in the call.

Comment: hey @crypto sahdev you can view this [contract-transfer unit test](https://github.com/paritytech/ink/blob/8c3f65c3368429c607f630920c424cb2004ae8ee/examples/contract-transfer/lib.rs#L64). There is a solution for set caller and pass funds to the call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [ink_env::test](https://docs.rs/ink_env/3.4.0/ink_env/test/index.html#functions) there are lots of test function which help you for your specification likes [get caller](https://docs.rs/ink_env/3.4.0/ink_env/test/fn.default_accounts.html), [set the caller](https://docs.rs/ink_env/3.4.0/ink_env/test/fn.set_caller.html) and  [pass the funds](https://docs.rs/ink_env/3.4.0/ink_env/test/fn.set_balance.html) and many more. Hope this helps your query.